# Как в kotlin выводить массив без квадратных скобок?

Tags: python, массивы, kotlin

У меня возникла проблема в выводе массива.
Я знаю, что есть в Python аналог вывода массива.

```py
a = [1, 5, 7]
print(*a) // вывод будет 1 5 7
```

Но есть ли способ такой же выводить массив в kotlin.
Через цикл for я знаю как выводить, хочется узнать, есть ли другие способы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val arr = arrayOf(1, 5, 7)
    println(arr.joinToString(" "))
}
```